# Appending string is not working

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm trying this code...

```
NSString *tileString = [[NSString alloc] init];    

for (int i = 0; i < [[GameP objectForKey:@"groundMap"] length]; i += 5) {

            tileString = [[GameP objectForKey:@"groundMap"] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 5)];

            [tileString stringByAppendingString:@"0000"];

            [sharedInstance.groundMap addObject:tileString];
        }
```

The 5 char string that's coming from the object is "t0001", so I want to end up with "t0001000" but it's not working, when I check sharedInstance.groundMap all the strings in the array are still "t0001"

Should I be using NSMutableString instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't assigning the result. Change this:

```
[tileString stringByAppendingString:@"0000"];
```

to:

```
titleString = [tileString stringByAppendingString:@"0000"];
```

There's a little more cleanup you can do too:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[GameP objectForKey:@"groundMap"] length]; i += 5) {
    NSString *tileString = [[GameP objectForKey:@"groundMap"] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 5)];
    titleString = [tileString stringByAppendingString:@"0000"];
    [sharedInstance.groundMap addObject:tileString];
}
```

Comment: Thanks,why in your version do I not need to alloc and init, is it already done by substringWithRange?

Comment: @Phil, yes substringFromRange returns a string, so your alloc init is unnecessary.

Comment: alloc/init is used to create a new object. You just need a reference to an existing one. What you had was a wasted string that was discarded as soon as you assigned another string to `tileString`.